# Is it possible to put two variable types in List?

Tags: java, variables, apache-poi

I was wondering how could i link my XSSFSheet by a string? I need a variable similar to Map, but it should return XSSFSheet, not object.

Something like this:

```
List<XSSFSheet, String> list = new ArrayList<XSSFSheet, String>

list.add(mySheet1, "ID154");
list.add(mySheet2, "ID4564");
list.get("ID4564"); //Gets mySheet1 by that ID
```

Comment: Why you complicate it, Why not a Map? with `Map<String, XSSFSheet>` ?

Comment: What you are describing looks exactly like a map to me. Can you explain in more detail why you don't want a map?

Comment: When i use map.get("ID154") it returns String, not XSSFRow and i cant use methods for that row.

Comment: Why do you want to do so with list? The list is not for the purpose you are trying using it. In case you just want to do so use **Pair** or your own object. And put it like - List<YourObject> testList = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Found the solution thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do so is a Map, but it would be a (very common) misuse of this datastructure. The correct way would be to create a simple dataholder class containing your two strings and have a List of objects of these datatypes.

On the other hand, reading your question again... a Map might not be so wrong at all in this case asy you have key-value-pairs.

So `Map<String, XSSFSheet> map = new HashMap<>()` should be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not. A list is an object for storing a collection of objects that are of the same type.to store key value pairs like what you want to do you'd need to use a HashMap object which is designed to store key, value pairs.

HashMaps come in the form `HashMap<key, value>` with `key` being the type for the key, and `value` being the type for the corresponding value.

Your code would then look like this:

```
HashMap<String, XSSFSheet> list = new HashMap<String, XSSFSheet>();

list.put("ID154", mySheet1);
list.put("ID4564", mySheet2);
list.get("ID4564"); //Gets mySheet1 by that ID
```

For more information [read this page](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/hashmap-in-java-with-example/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any structural overhead in using Map in your case. 
Complexity of accessing an entry in a HashMap is O(m), where m is the number of elements in the longest linked list associated with an entry in a HashMap.

But if you are very much specific in not using Map, then you can make use of the **KeyValue** Tuple from the **JavaTuples** library.

**A KeyValue is a Tuple from JavaTuples library that deals with only 2 elements – a key and a value.** 
Since this KeyValue is a generic class, it can hold any type of value in it.
Since KeyValue is a Tuple, hence it also has all the characterstics of JavaTuples:

- They are Typesafe
- They are Immutable
- They are Iterable
- They are Serializable
- They are Comparable (implements Comparable)
- They implement equals() and hashCode()
- They also implement toString()

**Class Declaration**

```
public final class KeyValue<A, B> extends Tuple 
           implements IValueKey<A>, IValueValue<B>
```

**Class hierarchy**

> Object   ↳ org.javatuples.Tuple
>         ↳ org.javatuples.KeyValue

So in your case you can use something like this.
Change according to your use case.

```
package com.test.UnitTests;

import java.util.*;
import org.javatuples.KeyValue;

class KeyValueTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KeyValue<Integer, String> kv1 = KeyValue.with(Integer.valueOf(1), "Maths");
        KeyValue<Integer, String> kv2 = KeyValue.with(Integer.valueOf(2), "English");
        List<KeyValue> testKVs = new ArrayList<KeyValue>();
        testKVs.add(kv1);
        testKVs.add(kv2);
        //assuming that you want to fetch the value for key = 2
        int key = 2;
        String value = fetchValue(key,testKVs);
        if(value!=null) {
            System.out.println("Value for Key: "+key +" = "+value);
        }else {
            System.out.println("No Key-Value pair found with Key:"+key);
        }
    }

    private static String fetchValue(int i, List<KeyValue> testKVs) {
        for (KeyValue testKv : testKVs) {
            if ((int) testKv.getKey() == i) {
                return (String)testKv.getValue();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

- To learn about javatuples more, use this link:
  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/keyvalue-class-in-java-tuples/
- You can download the jar at:
  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavatuples10jar.htm